# Nuxt and $auth in Fetch()

Tags: authentication, fetch, nuxt.js

I have a problem with my $auth...

In a page, i have to verify the $auth.loggedIn value.

```
<template>
   {{ this.$auth.loggedIn }}
</template>
<script>
   export default{
       async fetch(){
          if(this.$auth.loggedIn){
            console.log('User connected')
          }else{
            console.log('User not connected')
          }
       }
    }
</script>
```

The first $auth.loggedIn in my template is displaying TRUE (it's ok), but my console.log is displaying "User not connected"...

How it is possible ?
It seems i have the same issue with the $router / $route variable...

Thanks a lot!
Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` is called on **server-side** when rendering the route, and on **client-side** when navigating.

so if it's rendering your route, it initializes at server side and since `this.$auth` is only available on **client-side**, it has no access to it.

try accessing it via `app`

```
async fetch ({ app }) {
      if(app.$auth.loggedIn){
        console.log('User connected')
      }else{
        console.log('User not connected')
      }
}
```

**regarding param question**, you can accessing like below:

```
async fetch ({ params }) {
        console.log(params.id)
}
```

or

```
async fetch ({ route}) {
        console.log(route.params.id)
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. But so, how i can do ?
I need to construct my page in the fetch() according to the $auth.loggedIn value...!

Comment: I saw : "For plugins, asyncData, fetch, nuxtServerInit and Middleware, you can access it from context.$auth". But if i use contect.$auth,, i have an "undefined" error :(

Comment: @VinParker, try the code above for accessing $auth and see if it works.

Comment: it seems better for $auth, but now, i have an error with my this.$route.params.id (TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined).

Comment: @VinParker, updated my answer regarding params, try it.
please don't forget to mark it as best answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: if i need app AND route, AND params, can i write: async fetch ({ params, app, route })  ?

Comment: It seems OK. But now, i didnt' access my data anymore when i use "this". (thanks for helping me ;) )

Comment: @VinParker, can you explain further? what do you mean you didn't access data using `this.`